# "Install New Application" tab not visible in websphere application server base

Tags: centos, java, deployment, ibm, websphere

Recently I installed websphere application server base 64bit on centos os and dmgr and node agent working fine but In the console there are not options visible for create server, New application etc as below:

[image]

Please help to find issue.

Comment: Do you have multiple admin users defined?

Comment: Only one admin created at the time of installation. is this user related issue?

Comment: I thought it might be, but if you only have one user, it doesn't seem like it.